# generate html/asp dynamically

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a treeview type structure of folders/links that's populated from a table. What I was attempting to do was procedural loop through my recordset and generate my html in page_init and then try and bind the controls.  When I try to add the link buttons to the placeholders in html, it can never seem to find them.

I might be missing something fundamental here, all the examples i've seen bind a control thats already on the page, am I unable to generate the html myself in page_init?

example

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
  content_div.Innerhtml = "<asp:PlaceHolder id=""test"" runat=""server"" ></asp:PlaceHolder>"
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Dim _linkb As New LinkButton
   _linkb.ID = "lb_cat_" & cat.uID
   _linkb.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript: sltoggle('cat_" & cat.uID & "');")
   _linkb.Attributes.Add("Text", "Expand/Close")
   _linkb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
   Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(TRIEDEVERYTHINGUNDERTHESUN.FindControl("test"), PlaceHolder)
   ph.Controls.Add(_linkb)
End Sub
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be much appreciated

Regards,
Pete

UPDATE - full code

```
Private Sub load_dynamic_file_view()
    Dim _sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim _sfc As New sf_file_category, _sff As New sf_file
    _lsfc = _sfc.get_all_sf_file_category
    _lsff = _sff.get_active_sf_files

    Dim _list_root As List(Of sf_file_category) = _lsfc.FindAll(Function(p) p.parent_id = 0)
    If Not _list_root Is Nothing Then
        _sb.Append("<strong>File Downloads</strong><br />")
        _sb.Append("<div class=""indent-me"" ><br />")
        For Each cat As sf_file_category In _list_root
            'header/Open Link
            Dim _linkb As New LinkButton
            _linkb.ID = "lb_cat_" & cat.uID
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript: sltoggle('cat_" & cat.uID & "');")
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("Text", "Expand/Close")
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(Me.Master.FindControl("lb_cat_" & cat.uID), PlaceHolder)
            ph.Controls.Add(_linkb)

            _sb.Append(HtmlDecode(cat.name) & " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Asp:PlaceHolder id=""lb_cat_" & cat.uID & """ runat=""server"" /><br />")
            '_sb.Append("<div id=""cat_" & cat.uID & """ class=""toggle-hide"">")
            '_sb.Append(add_child_folder(cat.uID, content))
            '_sb.Append(show_files(cat.uID, content))
            '_sb.Append("</div><div class=""clearfix"" />")
        Next
        _sb.Append("</div>")
        _sb.Append("<br /><br />")
    End If

    content_div.InnerHtml = _sb.ToString
End Sub

Private Function add_child_folder(ByVal catid As Long, ByRef content As ContentPlaceHolder) As String
    Dim _sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim _cl As List(Of sf_file_category) = _lsfc.FindAll(Function(p) p.parent_id = catid)
    If Not _cl Is Nothing Then
        _sb.Append("<div class=""indent-me"" ><br />")
        'For Each _c As sf_file_category In _cl.OrderBy(Function(p) p.view_order)

        _cl.Sort(Function(c1 As sf_file_category, c2 As sf_file_category)
                     Return c1.view_order.CompareTo(c2.view_order)
                 End Function)

        For Each cat As sf_file_category In _cl
            Dim _linkb As New LinkButton
            _linkb.ID = "lb_cat_" & cat.uID
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript: sltoggle(&#39;cat_" & cat.uID & "&#39;);")
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("Text", "Expand/Close")
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            Content.Controls.Add(_linkb)

            _sb.Append(HtmlDecode(cat.name) & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Asp:LinkButton id=""lb_cat_" & cat.uID & """ runat=""server"" Text=""Expand/Close"" href=&#39;javascript: sltoggle(&#39;cat_" & cat.uID & "&#39;);&#39; /><br />")
            '_sb.Append("<div id=""cat_" & cat.uID & """ class=""toggle-hide"">")
            _sb.Append(add_child_folder(cat.uID, content))
            _sb.Append(show_files(cat.uID, content))
            '_sb.Append("</div><div class=""clearfix"" >")
        Next
        _sb.Append("</div><br />")
    End If

    Return _sb.ToString
End Function

Private Function show_files(ByVal catid As Long, ByRef content As ContentPlaceHolder) As String
    Dim _sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim _fl As List(Of sf_file) = _lsff.FindAll(Function(p) p.file_category = catid)
    If Not _fl Is Nothing Then
        _sb.Append("<div class=""indent-me"" ><br />")
        For Each _f As sf_file In _fl
            Dim _linkb As New LinkButton

            _linkb.ID = "file_" & _f.uID
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("onCommand", "download_file")
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("CommandArgument", _f.uID.ToString)
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("Text", _f.file_name)
            _linkb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            AddHandler _linkb.Command, AddressOf download_file
            content.Controls.Add(_linkb)

            _sb.Append("<asp:LinkButton id=""file_" & _f.uID & """ runat=""server"" onCommand=""download_file"" commandArgument=""" & _f.uID & """ Text=""" & _f.file_name & """ /><br />")
        Next
        _sb.Append("</div><br />")
    End If
    Return _sb.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your full code shows is that your building a massive string of HTML. This is fine for some *smaller* situations, but your code is clearly getting quite big now, and I would suggest you change this approach.

I would recommend that you declare web control equivalents, such as:

```
new HtmlGenericControl("div") instead of <div></div>
```

OR

```
new HtmlAnchor() OR new LinkButton() instead of <a></a>
```

In the example of a tree structure the HTML may look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="root.htm">ROOT</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="levelone">LEVEL 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To generate this in code you would do something similar to:

```
'Menu Holder
Dim treeStruct As HtmlGenericControl("ul")

'Root
Dim branch As HtmlGenericControl("li")
Dim branchItem as HtmlAnchor("a")

'Level 1 
Dim subLevel As HtmlGenericControl("ul")
Dim subBranch As HtmlGenericControl("li")
Dim subBranchItem as HtmlAnchor("a")

'Setup Level 1
subBranchItem.InnerText = "LEVEL 1"
subBranchItem.Href = "levelone"

subBranch.Controls.Add(subBranchItem)
subLevel.Controls.Add(subBranch)

'Setup Root
branchItem.InnerText = "ROOT"
branchItem.Href = "root.htm"

'Add Link To Root
branch.Controls.Add(branchItem)
'Add Sub Branch To Root
branch.Controls.Add(subLevel)

treeStruct.Controls.Add(branch)
```

**Important** The code above is just for examples sake, ideally you would separate the functionality into functions for branch creation and then loop through your elements with your for loop.

You will also notice that I have used an `<UL>` instead of `<DIV>` as I would consider a tree structure to be an un-ordered list. Plus, you will also get the styling benefit from this more ridged structure.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll have to take a look at it closer after work and see what I can get to work :)

Comment: Hi, I got this example working fine.  I wasn't able to customise it exactly how my boss wanted it so I'll have to try and tweak it/try something else but i've marked as answer so others can use.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's a nice way of regaining structure when you need to dynamically generate so much HTML. You can drop any type of controls into the `.Control.Add()` function, so you can always use `LiteralControl` to give you a bit more customization.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to add a placeholder to the `content_div`, however, what you are doing is rendering the tag as HTML content.

I don't know exactly what type of control `content_div` is, but can't you try:

```
content_div.controls.add(new placeholder() { ID = "test" });
```

This would then allow you to find the control within the `content_div` control.

**However**, what would probably be a much more concise solution for you might be the following:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Dim _linkb As New LinkButton
   _linkb.ID = "lb_cat_" & cat.uID
   _linkb.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript: sltoggle('cat_" & cat.uID & "');")
   _linkb.Attributes.Add("Text", "Expand/Close")
   //you don't need this when using code behind
   //_linkb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")

   //this will add your linkbutton to the content_div control
   content_div.Controls.Add(_linkb)
End Sub
```

Give this ago and you should find it to be a useful way of dynamically building your page with asp controls.

Comment: I am inserting my html into a div tag via the innerhtml property on page_init. so the placeholder tags should be inside this div on page_load, is this correct?

Comment: InnerHtml is a string, and it will only be rendered as HTML. If you want to add a control that you can later find with `FindControl`, then you need to add the control to the page, usually within another control or the page itself. One way of doing this is in my example, have you tried this?

Comment: just giving it a go now - i'll get back to you :)

Comment: I've tried this and got it to work but it adds it to the bottom of the div area and not at the positions I need to them to be, which was why I was trying to replace the tags in html :( Basically its to display a dynamic folder structure with links to download files.  My boss wants it styled and organised in a particular manner so I need to add a load of links in with the file ids and link the events to a generic file_download function behind.

Comment: What are the contents of the `content_div` control, and do you populate the control with content from code, or in the `.aspx` part of the page? You can add `PlaceHolder`'s in the same way as above, define it and drop it into your `content_div` at the positions your require, this will work if your programatically building your page, otherwise you could put the place holders in your `.aspx` to locate the correct positions.

Comment: Added full code above, as you can see its just meant to loop through my list and add the child nodes if you like, with the list of files under a category if there are any.  The linkbuttons for the categories are for sltoggle sections to hide/show the and the file link buttons are for downloads.  Or at least that was going to be the theory.  markup etc probably not correct yet, just trying to get some links working.

Comment: I've posted another answer, which is hopefully a little more relevant to the full code you've added. Keep in mind the idea of what I have described in this answer, as it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You generate only HTML tags and do not generate ASP.Net tags, as they can't be parsed by browser.

I think your code should be like

```
content_div.Innerhtml = "<div id='test'></div>"
```

ASP:Placeholder control is just a place holder and it is not equal to div HTML tag. 
For an example i gave div tag here.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net controls added as text are not known to the page and thus no viewstate / object is stored for it, thus you can never find it using Findcontrol.

Use the object of the control and add it to the parent control's Control collection
e.g.

```
div.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder() { ... });
```

Once you have added it before Render event , its state will be saved and accessable.